# Job search engine API

Tags: api, recommendation-engine

After doing research on Job Search Engine API's, I couldn't find any other than Indeed which rejected my request to use their API. I am wondering whether there are any other Job Search Engine API's.

Comment: Could you just scrape Google Jobs results? They aggregate data from many websites.

Answer (score 0):

What are the other solutions did you try out?

I have tried Google CTS. But it can only be used for searching your own jobs.

Have you tried LinkedIn Easy Apply? Or better yet, you can try the Voyager - their own search provider under the hood. Try F12 while searching jobs on their site.

Have you checked what Google uses when you search jobs on their website? It gives you  results which it gathers from crawling. Not sure if they provide an API to pull the same.